# can I change <link> tag attribute value?

Tags: jquery, tags

I would like to use jquery to update my  attribute value, because I want the visitor when click the facebook likes then the likes' post will show different thumbnail in one html.

```
<link rel="img_src" href="myimg.jpg">
```

so I try to use the following code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("link").attr("href", myLinkFromXML);
});
```

but seem like not work.

Do you guys have any idea on this?

Thanks for advance. :)

Comment: Do you want to change the href of _every_ link on the page, or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason your code shouldn't have worked, except it would wipe out every stylesheet link tag href also

To target a specific one:

```
$('link[rel="img_src"]').attr('href', myLinkFromXML);
```

Now the issue is variable `myLinkFromXML` defined? I suspect from it's name you want this done in the success of an xml ajax call

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** try this: http://jsfiddle.net/69v27/

Good link: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Also, **Prop vs Attr** - this is good read as well please see: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) (this link will elaborate on Prop api vs attr)

In case of single element that needs to be change I would suggest adding identity i.e. `id` attribute for the element and use like this `$('#id_of_link').prop('href','to_whatever')` or for using class in case of group of link `$('.class_of_link').prop('href','to_whatever')`. Or see comments below there is another way using your rel.

Please let me know if I missed anything,

Hope this helps

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("link").prop("href","mylinkfromxml");
    alert("New Link is ==> " + $("link").prop('href'));
});​
```

Comment: you really want to change all the guy's stylesheets?

Comment: somehow "href" seems like an attribute to me rather than a property

Comment: @Joy yeah funny that, hmm oh and by the just in case for OP this is good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @nbrooks please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr good explaination

Comment: @charlietfl yep Can do like this : `$('link[rel="img_src"]').prop` :). Nea, not all; as OP dint mention but yes can do this for specific but its mnot clear, for an individual he/she should use `id` or `class` for a group :) thanks for comment though, cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
  var newCSS = [];

   $.each(options.styles, function(index) {
    $('<link />', {
        href: '/styles/' + options.styles[index]['href'],
        media: 'screen',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        'class': 'dynamic_css'
    }).appendTo('head');
  });
  // IE doesn't always notice the presence of new stylesheets
  if ($.browser.msie) {
       $('.dynamic_css').clone().appendTo('head');
  }
```

This code will add new css to document. Use this style and change code accordingly for your xml